# Как исправить баг sticky topbar + выпадающие меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `topbar` для мобильной навигации, при скороле использую `sticky` от `foundation`, что бы прикрепить его к верхней части страницы. Когда полностью открывается меню/подменю оно больше чем основной контент страницы. `Sticky` + открытое подменю дает баг, что не возможно проскролить и увидеть полностью меню, в данном примере при открытом меню сначала скролится страница, а после меню, тогда как у меня на проекте оно вобще не скролится. Пытался убрать скролл у `html` и добавить его к блоку с навигацией, но не получилось.
Подскажите, как можно реализовать скрол у навигации пока открыто меню?
Или как подругому или более правильный вариант реализации данной задачи?

```js
$(document).foundation();
$(".js-show-sub").on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".nav__item--is-active").removeClass(".nav__item--is-active");
  $(this).parents("li").addClass("nav__item--is-active");
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.item {
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

//****//
.x-nav {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #193768;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .x-nav {
    height: auto;
  }
}

.x-nav__mobile-bar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #193768;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: background-color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.x-nav__mobile-bar--is-active {
  background-color: #318dde;
  transition: background-color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.x-nav__desctop {
  z-index: -1;
}

.x-nav__desctop {
  display: none;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #193768;
}

.nav__list,
.nav__inner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav__inner {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0.625rem;
  background-color: #1e427d;
}

.nav__item {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: middle;
  -ms-flex-align: middle;
  align-items: middle;
  transition: background-color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav__item:hover {
  background-color: #318dde;
  transition: background-color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav__item--is-active .nav__inner {
  display: block;
}

.nav__link {
  padding: 0.625rem 0.9375rem;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}


}
.nav__dropdown {
  width: 45px;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  background-color: #16305c;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav__link,
.nav__link:hover,
.nav__link:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.0-rc.3/dist/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.0-rc.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="header" id="header">HEADER</header>
<div class="x-layout__nav" data-sticky-container>
  <div class="x-nav sticky" data-sticky data-options="marginTop: 0;" data-top-anchor="header:bottom">
    <div class="x-nav__mobile-bar" data-toggler=".x-nav__mobile-bar--is-active" id="mobile-bar">
      <div class="x-nav__toggler">
        <span class="humburger" data-toggle="nav mobile-bar" style="color: #fff; cursor: pointer;">Show menu</span>
      </div>
      <div class="x-nav__lang" style="color: #fff;">
        ENG
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav sticky x-nav__desctop" id="nav" data-toggler data-animate="slide-in-down slide-out-up">
      <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="news.html" class="nav__link js-show-sub">Click!</a>
          <ul class="nav__inner">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.2</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.3</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.4</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.5</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.6</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.8</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.9</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.10</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.12</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 1.13</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="news.html" class="nav__link js-show-sub">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="news.html" class="nav__link js-show-sub">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="news.html" class="nav__link js-show-sub">Item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 6</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="news.html" class="nav__link">Item 7</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <!--<div class="item"></div> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.nav {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
}`